# wgt downloads all files except for the images i want

Tags: script, download, wget, web-crawler

i have trouble using wget to download images from a gallery.
as start i use the overwiew page. it has thumbs that link to the individual pages with the large images.

here is the script i use:

```
wget --recursive --accept=jpg,jpeg,html,htm -p --level=2 http://www.site.com/page/page/number.htm
```

when i run this script, all files including the thumbs and individual imagepages are downloaded, but not the large images. however according to the documentation wget should download all files necessary to display the pages with the parameter "-p".
could anyone please point out what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

### Javascript?

It is possible that the individual image pages use Javascript to load the actual images. You can tell by inspecting the source HTML for one of the individual pages.

This sort of thing is sometimes done to discourage people from writing scripts to download all the images. Perhaps the image owners are concerned about copyright infringement.

Update your question and add a link the the gallery overview page for more detailed assistance.